# Empty pages in the preface section of my thesis

Tags: page-breaking, document-classes, report

I am writing a thesis and I'd like to use the openright option:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
```

The problem is that when I use this option, empty pages are placed between different sections of the preface. i.e. abstract - empty page - table of contents - list of figures - empty page - list of tables... etc.

I looked at the *thesis.sty provided by my department* and I noticed that each section of the preface are formatted to behave like chapters.

```
\def\prefacesection#1{
    \chapter*{#1} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
```

I tried changing this code snippet so that sections of the preface are actually treated as sections

```
\def\prefacesection#1{
    \section*{#1} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
```

Although this removed the empty pages, I was disappointed with the results. Firstly, the ToC, LoF, and LoT were not affected by this change (I assume their style is defined elsewhere).  Secondly, I strongly preferred the look and style as it was before I made any changes to the preface style.

Is there anyway I can selectively apply the openright option so that the contents of the preface are unaffected? Or is there a better way to fix my problem with empty pages in the preface?

Comment: The toc line is styled by the code you showed if you changed `chapter` to `section` it would be styled like a section in teh table of contents

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I wrote that the ToC, LoF and LoT were unaffected, I wasn't referring to the ToC line. I was referring to the appearance of the actual pages themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The toc line is styled by the code you showed: if you changed `chapter` to `section` it would be styled like a section in the table of contents

you can switch openright styles in your frontmatter using

```
\csname @openrightfalse\endcsname
```

and

```
\csname @openrighttrue\endcsname
```